# PuTTY telnet strange output

Tags: lisp, newline, telnet, putty

I am serving a Lisp system from `patrickconnelly.net` on port 65000 for my college senior project.  I tested remote access from the terminal (I run Slackware 14.0) and all was well.  One of my group members successfully connected using PuTTY, but was unable to enter commands.  Connecting in RAW mode allowed proper interaction with the server, but the output is displayed strangely.  Every line seems to get tabbed over several times further than the one before it.  I am clueless, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

By the way the output when connecting with PuTTY looks like

```
you must choose:
                R: Steel Bank Common Lisp REPL
                                              C: tasty treat
                                                            B: compliment two
                                                                             etc
```

When it ought to be

```
you must choose:
R: Steel Bank Common Lisp REPL
C: tasty treat
B: compliment two
A: compliment one
```

Comment: Does PuTTY run on Windows? Is there an option to convert <newline> to <carriage return>+<newline> ?

Comment: Thanks, uselpa.  PuTTY does run on Windows.  A group member brought the issue to my attention, so I found a build for Linux.  It turns out that there is such an option.  Under the Terminal settings to use "Implicit CR in every LF" and to use "Implicit LF in every CR".  This solved the issue.  Though my lisp code uses "~%" in format statements to output newlines.  I think the behavior of "~%" in format statements is system-dependent...it seems to make sense that since the server runs Linux, CRLF would not be used by default.